# Gradle: add dependency for a specific flavour of the library

Tags: android, gradle, library-project, android-productflavors

I have a library project and a application. I'd like to have 2 product flavours (*store*, *dev*) for both library and application. When I build the *store* flavour for the application I want to use the *store* flavour from the library. Also when I build the *dev* flavour for the application I want to use the *dev* flavour from the library. I tried setting the same product flavours for both library and application but it does not work.

Here is my configuration:

*Library*

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ro.amarkovits.graddletest.lib"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors{
        store{

        }
        dev{

        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

and I have this files:
src/main/res/values/strings.xml
and 
src/store/res/values/strings.xml

*Application*

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'ro.amarkovits.mymodule.app'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors{
        store{

        }
        dev{

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':lib')
}
```

In this situation I get this error: Error:(12, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/app_name'). The *app_name* is defined in *string.xml* in the library (in both *main* and *store* directory)

If I remove the productFlavors from the library it builds but always use the *values.xml* from the *main* directory

Comment: I edited my question with more details

Comment: @galex no, and I stopped searching

Comment: @amarkovits found it, check my response!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In your library you need to tell gradle to build every time every variant:

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

Then in your application, since recently I guess, you can do this:

```
dependencies {
    (...)
    devCompile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'devDebug') // or 'devRelease'
    storeCompile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'storeRelease') // or 'storeDebug'
}
```

Found in the official documentation under [Library Publication](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication).

Edit:

Since version [0.14.3 (2014/11/18)](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), you can now have Flavor-buildType-Compile directive as well:

In your build.gradle before the android {} scope add the following:

```
configurations {
    devDebugCompile
    devReleaseCompile
    storeDebugCompile
    storeReleaseCompile
}
```

Then you can declare and use different versions of your library per Flavor-BuildType:

```
dependencies {
    (...)
    devDebugCompile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'devDebug')
    devReleaseCompile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'devRelease')
    storeDebugCompile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'storeDebug')
    storeReleaseCompile project(path: ':lib', configuration: 'storeRelease') 
}
```

Edit:

Dependency management between modules has changed since **Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0**. It automatically tries to matches flavours between your app and the libraries/modules it depends on.

See the [documentation for the whole explanation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_aware)!

Comment: Any idea how to do this so devDebug uses devDebug, and devRelease uses devRelease (doesn't make sense in this case, but does for my use case)?

Comment: There is no "per variant", only per-flavor or per-buildType compile keyword for now.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia I edit my answer as what you asked for actually now exists

Comment: do we need to add module again in module settings ? or above code is good enough ?

Comment: @Meher what do you mean in module settings ? In settings.gradle ? Yes your library defined as module needs to be there, otherwise gradle does not know it is  there to be built.

Comment: Very helpful answer! This information, along with this post: https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/android/android-gradle-configurations/ helped me figure out my gradle compile issues with missing packages and symbols.

Comment: it seems not working for latest AS. it cannot fetch the project if I specify the `configuration`

Comment: @IHC_Applroid didn't try it yet but replace the keyword "Compile" by "Implementation" ?

Comment: @galex no, AS changed the way it works. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: @galex please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215663/android-studio-3-0-submodule-compile-failed

Comment: _configurations {. . .}_ Thanks for hint. Though editor provide you auto selection while adding dependency for flavour but you have to defined same in _configurations_ block.

Comment: I would say there is a good web-page with a detailed explanation how to do it, see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolve_matching_errors

Answer (score 5):

To define specific dependency for each flavor you can use "nameOfTheFlavorCompile" instead of "compile"

```
dependencies {
    storeCompile project(':lib')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue a while ago, what happens is that the compiler ignores product flavors for the library project. Moreover, even when you add more build types, it keeps looking for and compiling release/debug sources.

The reason is simple:

- Product flavors are not supported for the library plugin.
- The only build types supported seem to be debug and release.

The compiler will **never** look for anything you put in the store directory of your library project. So, you need to find a way around it.

One way around it would be to include both implementations with a level of abstraction in your library (through interfaces, multiple constructors, etc), and then let your app project decide which part of the library to run. If you use proguard, it will automatically get rid of the unneeded code, if it is decoupled well enough (and possibly so even if it is not).