# No matching client found for package name (Google Analytics) - multiple productFlavors & buildTypes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-analytics, android-productflavors

**Context:**

I'm trying to set up Google Analytics for my app. (having 4 custom `buildTypes` and more than a few `productFlavors`)

It works fine when I select the `Build Variant` which has the `applicationId` set to `com.my.app.package.name` (the package name used when generating the `google-services.json`). But, my other flavors have different applicationIds.

I followed the [offical devguide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) to set it up.

Error I get when any another build variant is selected in `Build Variants Tab` (which has a different `applicationId` (package name) is as follows:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processAllcategoriesDebugfreeGoogleServices'.
>
> > No matching client found for package name 'com.my.app.package.name.debug'

**Explanation of Error Message:**

In the task name in the error message above `Debugfree` is my custom `buildType` and `Allcategories` is one of my `productFlavors`.

***I understand the error and know the package name is different from what i used when generating the json, but that is what I'm trying to figure a way around.***

**Problem:**

Now, the `google-services.json` resides in the `app` folder and hence I am not being able to separate them out for each product flavor by dropping them in the flavor specific source set folder.

**Questions:**

1. My custom `byildType` for debugging suffixes `.debug` to the `applicationId` (package name). Is there a way I can make it work with the `google-services.json` which has my release `applicationId` (i.e. without the suffix `.debug`)
2. Is there a way to have multiple product flavors configured in the same `google-services.json` file without using separate files and tasks to copy the required file to `app` folder. I know it can be done using `task` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors). Is there a simpler way to just have one file or pick right file based on gradle configuration?
3. I see the `package_name` field in `google-services.json` has the package name `com.my.app.package.name`. Can I add multiple package names manually to work for all build variants? If yes, how to do that? Could not find any instructions in documentations.

Comment: Did you find a soution especially for your third question?

Comment: I'm in similar situations. I need analytics support for one of prod-release flavour version only. I could able to [limit added dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26249615/2624806) to prod-flavour but it still search for right package as part of son file. Any suggestion !

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Let me know if anyone finds the solution for this?

Comment: in my case, i just changed the package name

Comment: if your using firebase in app  then add your new applicationId as sub app(add app) issue will fix

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Found this:

> The google-services.json file is generally placed in the app/
>   directory, **but as of version 2.0.0-alpha3 of the plugin support was
>   added for build types**, which would make the following directory
>   structure valid:
>
> ```
> app/src/
>     main/google-services.json
>     dogfood/google-services.json
>     mytype1/google-services.json
>     ...
> ```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

[Source 2](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54#issuecomment-165824720)

Comment: Is there any way to disable analytics easily for a build type? I want to disable it for Debug? I thought it would be disabled if I don't add google-services file, but even if I disable, it still asks for google-services file.

Comment: What would the difference each of the josn file added in each flavour??

Comment: Is there a possibility to use google services inside a module (that two apps share)... cause i can't even gradle-sync without having a google service file for that package... the embedding app should provide the json, but not the module. is this anyhow possible?

Comment: When I moved `google-service.json` to new folder named `staging` I got this error: ```File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
```. I need firebase only for staging, still - this doesn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 700):

Check your package name on your  **google-services.json** it should be same with your local package name of your app

**Example**

```
"client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:6596814400689:android:65d6f25f5006145",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.my.app.package.name"
    }
```

In this case my local package name is **com.my.app.package.name** so also i have changed my package name in **google-services.json** with my local package name

Comment: google-services.json is a file!!! within a app directory. Should find this file with the help of the Windows Explorer (for example). Should edit this file by the usual editor.

Comment: to find this go to Project view in Android Studio and search inside your app package

Comment: No... we all know **google-services.json** is invalid in this issue...

What we want is how to solve this issue in build variant situation!!

Comment: If your activity is in a subpackage such as: com.example.aaron.myproject22.Activities.... you need to go into the google-services.json and change the client_info's package_name to com.example.aaron.myproject22 Also make sure you have apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of build.grade (Module app)

Comment: This fixed it for me. I'm using Firebase push notifications inside a library, and the google-services.json file that the Firebase Console generated used the app's package name instead of the library's package name. Thanks!

Answer (score 179):

**No matching client found for package name 'com.tf'**
I am pretty sure that the "package_name" in google-services.json is not matching with your "applicationId" in app gradle.

app gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tf" //replace with the package_name in google-services.json =
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

---

google-services.json

```
"client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:23978655351:android:2b2fece6b961cc70",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "in.ac.geu.debug"
        }
      },
```

**Solution**:  Just make sure the `package_name` and `applicationId` must be same.

Comment: Author was asking about a workaround to this. They have different build types with different applicationId

Comment: you have given to most valid solution. Kudos man !!

Comment: The `application id` in app gradle nailed it

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just make sure the package_name = applicationId.

In my case, I was created a new project with a new name (A) and copy the old code from old project named (B). In project B the package_name is the name I chose on firebase console, but it is not matter, we do not need to match the name we have set on the SDK installation instruction.

Answer (score 91):

I have found the solution:

We have to create two "apps" in the firebase project, and then we can download json file from any one app (I downloaded from the flavoured app). It will contain the data for both the apps. We can simply copy the json file to the app's root directory.

Source: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Comment: This is the best answer as all the product flavours can be covered by one json file. No need to create other sourcesets.

Comment: Please note, you have to create the apps inside the same project. Project Overview on the upper left corner has a settings icon. Press it and it will open to the General tab, scroll down and under Your Apps section there is a button Add App

Comment: The biggest problem will happen when you forget to change your google-service.json  and push it to prod.

Comment: @galaxigirl Creating two apps in the same project will require a different package ID. How to handle it?

Comment: @usman Creating two apps in the same project will require a different package ID. How to handle it?

Answer (score 84):

> **Whenever you create or update `package name` Make sure your package name is exactly the same *[Upper case and lower case matters]***

Do below step.

**1).** Check `applicationId` in App level `gradle` file,

**2).** Check `package_name` in your `google-services.json` file,

**3).** Check `package` in your `AndroidManifest` file

and for full confirmation make sure that your working package directory name *i.e.("com.example.app")* is also the same.

> EDIT [ Any one who is facing this issue in `productFlavour` scenario, go check out [Droid Chris's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51389929/4696610) ]

Comment: Thanks Bro it worked for me .In app level gradle file my package was different .When I changed it worked for me

Comment: wel come @fazil

Comment: You don't have to change `package` in manifest (and all files in all packages), as `applicationId` will change app id.

Comment: This is not what the author was asking about

Answer (score 78):

make sure your package name in "google-services.json" file is same with your apps's package name.

Comment: common issue when forking a repo for a new project.

Comment: yes if both package name are not same than it is not working

Answer (score 66):

First off, add a suffix to the application package in Gradle:

```
yourFlavor {
   applicationIdSuffix "yourFlavor"
}
```

This will cause your package to be named

```
com.domain.yourapp.yourFlavor
```

Then go to Firebase under your current project and add another android app to it with this package name.

Then replace the existing google-services.json file with the new one you generate with the new app in it.

Then you will end up with something that has multiple "client_info" sections. So you should end up with something like this:

```
"client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "YOUR APP INFO",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.domain.yourapp"
    }
  }

"client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "YOUR APP INFO - will be different then other app info",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.domain.yourapp.yourFlavor"
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is the right answer! You need both Apps (ids) in the google-services.json file.

Comment: this is the way. +1, here's some [old discussion](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54#issuecomment-181807020) that relates to this issue

Comment: Simple and straight forward.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer regarding build variants

Comment: even tho I have answered to this question here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906585/4696610], but for the `productFlavour` scenario, this is the best solution, I will sure link your answer in mine to help future devs, thx +1

Comment: Correct answer !! Worked ,Thanks

Comment: this did not work for me

Comment: @AnnaHarrison post your code and see what your issue is. It seems now that Firebase automatically does what I had posted here.

Comment: @DroidChris
Is there a way to do it through the build script, rather than manually appending each product flavor's entry at the `google-services.json` file? I can't even tell what the value of the `mobilesdk_app_id` property.

Comment: You should add all your project ids in the google-services.json like I put in the post. Then when you used build variants, in gradle, make the product id different between builds.

Comment: @polendina if you are still having issues feel free to reach out and we can fix

Answer (score 59):

This error occurs when you have a Google Services Json file downloaded in your project whose Package name **doesn't match with your Project's package name**.

**Recently renamed the project's package name?**

It does update all the classes **but not the Gradle File**. So check if your package name is correct in your Gradle, and also maybe Manifest too.

Answer (score 46):

You need to place `google-services.json` into `app/` dir. And for each build type, there should be accordant director in
`app/src` folder.

For example, if you have release and debug:

```
app/google-services.json
app/src/debug/google-services.json
```

In all google-services.json files you should specify correct `package_name` according to build type.

For example, inside debug dir it should be like `{com.myapp}.debug`

Comment: Apparently you can even just duplicate the main set's element in the `"client"`'s array (add a comma between the elements) and change just the `"package_name"`'s value of the new element to include the `.debug` suffix. Then rebuild. It worked for me on AS 2.3.3.

Answer (score 32):

1.Verify **Package name** and **Application ID** should be same

2.Verify **google-services.json package name** which is available in app folder

Comment: I had to `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` as well to get this working.

Answer (score 26):

check if `client_id` and `package_name` in the **google-services.json** has a correct value according to your package name.

You should add the mentioned file into the flavors directory with corresponding package name in the `client_id` and `package_name` field.

Answer (score 21):

In my case I forgot google-services.json in app root directory which was for different flavour. It was used by default instead of using json stored in flavour's folder. This messed up plugin and since package names were not matching it failed.

Wisdom I taught, check for all google-services.json in your project structure when this problem occurs.

Answer (score 21):

If anyone change their existing package name then sometimes it makes problem like that, so you should change local package name, **build.gradle** file package name and if your project have any **google-services.json** file then simply you need to change your JSON file package name too.

**Old File look like that**

```
"client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:517104510151:android:8b7ed3989db24a6f928ae2",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.techsajib.oldapp"
    }
  },
```

**New File look like that**

```
"client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:517104510151:android:8b7ed3989db24a6f928ae2",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.techsajib.newapp"
    }
  },
```

**Note:** sometimes JSON file have several package name so change all of them

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you rename ApplicationId in gradle file after rename your package

Comment: Saved me. Thanks.

Comment: glad it helped someone

Comment: Solved my problem too!

Answer (score 17):

Open your Google-services.json file and look for this section in the file:

```
"client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:857242555489:android:46d8562d82407b11",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.example.duke_davis.project"
    }
  }
```

check whether the package is the same as your package name. Mine was different, so I changed it and it worked.

Comment: Worked :)
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Only two easy step to change package name:

1. Open *"build.gradle"* file
   [image]
2. Then add your new package name in *"applicationId"*, now then click on "sync now" the project.

[image]

**Note:** If your "google-services.json" file is added in project then change your name package name there inside **"client_info"**

[image]

package name inside "google-services.json"

[image]

That's all. No need to change package name anywhere else.

Answer (score 11):

Im coming from react native but I think that this applies to this question as well. To specify.

Within the file `android/app/build.gradle` search for `applicationId` (within `android`, `defaultConfig`)

and ensure that that value is the same this

`client[0]client_info.android_client_info.package_name`

as the value within `google-services.json`.

Answer (score 10):

You also need to change package name in **google-services.json**

Answer (score 8):

If your package name on Google-services.json file is okay,
Go to gradle.properties file. Then change your APPLICATION_ID="com.yourpackage.name"

Answer (score 6):

I think you have added firebase json file "google-services".json with the new file. Make sure to create a new file [check the link on how to create json file from firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHkn_WeGMEI) and it should match with your package name

Second thing is that if you are changing the package name use the option " replace in path" when you right click under files when you select project from the drop down. You have to search for package name in the whole project and replace it !

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 4):

if none of it worked for one of you guys, my problem was with a package name that didn't start with a 'com'.
changed it, now it works.

hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem by re-syncing the file `google-services.json`.

> Tools > Firebase > Connect to Firebase > Sync

Comment: where did you do that? what does it replace exactly? Screenshot?

Comment: You can do that in Android Studio (Firebase plugin must be enabled). It updates the file `google-services.json`.

Answer (score 3):

go your project directory and create folders on app/src path that named your product flavors (like Alpha, Beta, Store or what ever your flavor's name is). then copy your google-services.json file to each folder. don't forget to change "package_name" field on your each product flavor's google-services.json file that you subfoldered.

Answer (score 3):

Go to google-services.json file and in client part check the package name and compare it with App package name if they are different then change the client package name according to your app package name it worked for me best of luck..

google-services.json file->  "package_name": "com.example.application.tracker"

App package name->package "com.example.application.tracker";

Answer (score 3):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

make sure Gradle.app's applicationId is same your package name. my problem was this and  I solved this way

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by making two sourcesets , one free and one paid. Both of these folders will contain required java code and resource files, which will be edited to the requirements of the particular flavor. For example, You would like to remove AdMob Code in the Paid both from Java Classes and Layout Files.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem 
here is simple solution:
when you create **firebase** connection follow these guidelines:

- Add your application name in firebase
- Add your application pakage name (write same pakage name ,you are using in app)
- when firebase make **google-services.json** file just **download** it and **paste** it in your app folder
- Sync your project Problem is solved :)

  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I also get this issue when i change package name of my application.

In your android studio project find "google-services.json" file.
Open it.
and check whether package name of your application is same as written in this file.

The package name of your application and package name written in "google-services.json" file must be same.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that for sovling this problem.

[image]

Comment: This will mask the problem instead of solving it. See other answers for a solution.

Comment: Please use code instead of a screenshot, your answer is good in my case because I only want to create a "mockup" of an application clone.

Comment: Sharing the code rather than screenshot would have been more useful.

Answer (score 1):

This means your google-services.json file either does not belong to your application(Did you download the google-services.json for another app?)...so to solve this do the following:

**1:Sign in to Firebase and open your project.
2:Click the Settings icon and select Project settings.
3:In the Your apps card, select the package name of the app you need a config file for from the list.
4:Click google-services.json.**
After the download completes,add the new google-services.json to your project root folder,replacing the existing one..or just delete the old one.
Its very normal to download the google-services.json for your first project and then assume or forget that this specific google-services.json is tailored for your current project alone,because not any other because all projects have a unique package name.

Answer (score 1):

Check for `applicationIdSuffix` in your app's build.gradle file. See if it is concatenating any text to your `applicationId`. If so, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If your `applicationId` is different between your `buildTypes`, you can add those particular artifacts to specific dependency flavor like `releaseImplementation` for example.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add `SHA certificate fingerprint` in Firebase. I just re-imported `google-services.json` and it worked

Answer (score -1):

Just simple. Sign-out from Android Studio, close it completely. Reopen Android studio and then again Sign-In to Android Studio.

Then try to connect to firebase from the Android studio IDE. This procedure worked for me.

Comment: this is not working if google-services.json exists. we must delete google-services.json if it exists.

Comment: this will work once after you change the package name in the json file as well and before save that, you need to close the android studio and then save the json file and restart the studio.

Answer (score -3):

It is simple to solve this: just make sure the package name in your app/build.gradle file is this same package name as the ones in your App Manifest file. and ensure the package name is correct. That should solve this