# How to maintain two google-services.json, production and debug

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am including feature of gcm in my app, For that i need to maintain two google-services.json one for **debug** and one for **release** build. How to do that ?? 
 can i configure gcm without using google-services.json ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No matching client found for package name (Google Analytics) - multiple productFlavors & buildTypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf)

Answer (score 7):

First, place the respective google_services.json for each buildType in the following locations:

```
app/src/debug/google_services.json
app/src/test/google_services.json
app/google_services.json
```

Note: Root app/google_services.json This file should be there according to the build variants copy the json code in the root json file

Now, let’s whip up some gradle tasks in your: app’s build.gradle to automate moving the appropriate google_services.json to app/google_services.json

copy this in the app/Gradle file

```
task switchToDebug(type: Copy) {
description = 'Switches to DEBUG google-services.json'
from "src/debug"
include "google-services.json"
into "."
}

task switchToRelease(type: Copy) {
description = 'Switches to RELEASE google-services.json'
from "src/release"
include "google-services.json"
into "."
}
```

Great — but having to manually run these tasks before you build your app is cumbersome. We would want the appropriate copy task above run sometime before: assembleDebug or :assembleRelease is run. Let’s see what happens when :assembleRelease is run: copy this one in the /gradlew file

```
Zaks-MBP:my_awesome_application zak$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
.... (other tasks)
:app:processReleaseGoogleServices
....
:app:assembleRelease
```

Notice the :app:processReleaseGoogleServices task. This task is responsible for processing the root google_services.json file. We want the correct google_services.json to be processed, so we must run our copy task immediately beforehand.
Add this to your build.gradle. Note the afterEvaluate enclosing.

copy this in the app/Gradle file

```
afterEvaluate {
processDebugGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToDebug
processReleaseGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToRelease
 }
```

Now, anytime :app:processReleaseGoogleServices is called, our newly defined :app:switchToRelease will be called beforehand. Same logic for the debug buildType. You can run :app:assembleRelease and the release version google_services.json will be automatically copied to your app module’s root folder.

Credit goes to the : Zak Taccardi
https://medium.com/google-cloud/automatic-per-variant-google-services-json-configurations-with-gradle-d3d3e40abc0e

Answer (score 6):

The current plugin (`com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.X`) supports ***flavors*** but not **types**.

So if you create a productflavor you can put the json file in `src/$flavorname`

Example:

```
app/src/
    flavor1/google-services.json
    flavor2/google-services.json
```

Currently it doesn't work with types (debug, release...) but you can use somenthing like this:

```
app/src/release/google-services.json
app/google-services.json
```

In this case the plugin looks in the locations and stops when it finds a google-services.json file.

If you are using a flavor it becomes:

```
app/src/foo/release/google-services.json
app/src/foo/google-services.json
```

You can find updated info [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54).

Comment: What about the latest plugin? Does it support types?

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently using the following versions: com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3, com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0

Place your `google-services.json` file in your `$projectName/app/src/$buildType` directory. For example, place one json file in `src/release` and another in `src/debug`. You will likely need to create the release & debug folders.

**Note:** It's a common mistake to add these files in the app folder, be sure you add this in the src folder as described above.

> The google-services plugin always looks for the google-services.json
> file in two directories: First, on the
> $projectName/app/src/$buildType/google-services.json. If it does not
> find it here, it goes one level above, to the
> $projectName/app/google-services.json. So, when you are building the
> debug version of your app, it will search for the google-services.json
> on the $projectName/app/src/debug/ directory.

At the link below, see [David Ojeda's response](https://medium.com/@david_ojeda/thanks-for-the-post-zak-taccardi-5a57489388ac).

Comment: I have only src/debug folder which holds for the debug build. Another for production app which is contained in src/google_services.json. Both the files have array of "client_info" object for both com.myapp.debug and com.myapp. Is that correct ?

Comment: That may or may not work but my answer says to put your production google services in the src/release folder, not the src folder. That's how i did mine.