# How to support multiple Firebase environment in Javascript Web especially in Flutter

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web

To support a single environment, the following code works fine in my flutter web index.html

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- Firebase Configuration -->
    <script>
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "[YOUR_PROJECT].firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://[YOUR_PROJECT].firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "[YOUR_PROJECT]",
        storageBucket: "[YOUR_PROJECT].appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "...",
        appId: "1:...:web:...",
        measurementId: "G-...",
      };

      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

However, how to support multiple Firebase environments in Flutter Web?

For example, along with the above, I want to have two additional Environment named `dev` and `preprod`
For Dev, a different configuration:

```
         var firebaseConfigDev = {
            apiKey: "...",
            authDomain: "[YOUR_PROJECT_DEV].firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://[YOUR_PROJECT_DEV].firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "[YOUR_PROJECT_DEV]",
            storageBucket: "[YOUR_PROJECT_DEV].appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "...",
            appId: "1:...:web:...",
            measurementId: "G-...",
          };
```

And for preprod, another configuration

```
         var firebaseConfigPreprod = {
            apiKey: "...",
            authDomain: "[YOUR_PROJECT_PREPROD].firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://[YOUR_PROJECT_PREPROD].firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "[YOUR_PROJECT_PREPROD]",
            storageBucket: "[YOUR_PROJECT_PREPROD].appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "...",
            appId: "1:...:web:...",
            measurementId: "G-...",
          };
```

I searched everywhere on the internet and StackOverflow and could not find an example of how to achieve this. I however found it on Android, it is easy as [How to maintain two google-services.json, production and debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000261/how-to-maintain-two-google-services-json-production-and-debug) and using build flavors.

But in flutter web, what is the equivalent of build flavors and google service json ?

Answer (score 2):

As of now, unlike for mobile applications, there seems to be no easy way to achieve this in Flutter web.

Although as an alternative, you can achieve this through your web **build pipeline**.

- Save index.html as a template (ex. index.html.template) in your project with all firebase configs defined as ***environment variables***, and replace these variables to generate the actual index.html during the build
- Populate these environment variables in the pipeline based on what environment the build is targeting (dev, preprod, prod, etc.), which in turn would make the respective index file
- This way you can achieve dynamic builds with different Firebase configs

Comment: Good suggestion

Comment: Are these env variables in Github for example, or in the repo?

Comment: Do you have any link that we follow to setup this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this:

1. Create separate index.html files for your environments, for example, `index.html.pord` and `index.html.dev`. Write whatever in your index.html files to configure your environment.
2. Create a bash script `index-environment.sh` in your project root and copy the following code:

   if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0  <copy_filename>"
   exit 1
   fi

   filename=$1
   copy_filename="index.html"

   cp "./web/$filename" "./web/$copy_filename"
   echo "File copied from $filename to $copy_filename"

This code takes a takes any file and creates a copy of it with the name `index.html`

3. Before you run `flutter build ...` you run either `bash index-environment.sh index.html.dev` or `bash index-environment.sh index.html.prod` to generate an `index.html` you want to use for your current build.

You can use this in your deployment pipeline. I, for example, deploy my flutter app on vercel, where I have separate projects for prod and dev. I use the build command `bash index-environment.sh index.html.dev && flutter build web` to build my web app with the correct index.html