# No matching client found for package name 'org.apache.cordova'

Tags: android, apache, cordova, firebase

I'm creating a simple Cordova application (android/iOS) that makes use of Azure services such as authorisation and push notifications.

I've run into an error that I have not managed to fix. When building the app I get the following error:

```
    Error: /*path*/ Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugGoogleServices'.
    > No matching client found for package name 'org.apache.cordova'
```

The package name in config.xml, google-services.json, and AndroidManifest.xml are all the same, excluding in android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml (in which it is org.apache.cordova). When I try changing this a bunch of other errors arise.

I've redownloaded the google-services.json file and tried any solutions I found online, however nothing has worked.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are there any issues building for iOS? Have you tried removing android and readding it and then building?

Comment: It builds successfully for iOS. Removing android, adding it and rebuilding made no difference.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf