# google-services.json No matching client found for package name with any module

Tags: android, firebase

I renamed my **app** module in application to **presentation** module.

- I put google-services.json in my presentation/
- Added `classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0"`
- Added plugin: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

And when i try Sync gradle, i get error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':presentation:processDebugGoogleServices'.
No matching client found for package name 'ru.company.acitive.activelife'
```

My build.gradle snippet:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0"
}
```

My presentation/build.gradle snippet:

```
dependencies {

...

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That means your app's application ID is "ru.company.acitive.activelife", but that same string wasn't found in your google-services.json file.

Looks like there's a typo in the part where it says "acitive".  Should it be "active" instead?

Comment: I was facing the same issue. After seeing your answer I've just checked again and found a typo in my gradle file. I wrote `com.example.developmnet` in gradle but Firebase contains: `com.example.development`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ensuring that your gradle androidApplicationID matches your google-services.json (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf)), this message can also result from gradle not finding your keystore file.

Be sure to have these entries in your project level build.gradle file:

```
keystoreStoreFile = _________
keystoreStorePassword = ____________
keystoreKeyAlias = _______________
keystoreKeyPassword = ____________
```

And be sure to use the same four values when Android Studio prompts you for them during a "Generate Signed APK" opertation.

In my case, I was trying to build the example application [ClassyTaxi](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiAppKotlin) that Google provides for illustrating subscription services.  It has a project level build.gradle file that references a keystorePropertiesFile=keystore.properties.  That properties file didn't exist, but there was an example-keystore.properties file that I renamed to keystore.properties and populated it with the four values I had selected.  I then used those exact same four values when using Android Studio to generate my signed APK.

Answer (score 1):

In my own case, the line below in my app-level **build.gradle** file was the culprit:

```
applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
```

I inherited the codebase from another developer, so I wasn't initially aware that this line existed.