# Trying to connect Firebase to app but error which didn't exist 4 monthes ago

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to connect Firebase to project and got this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
```

> No matching client found for package name 'com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat'

My gradle project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle APP

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have adde google-services.json in APP folder. And like 4 monthes ago everything worked well. But now it doesn't.

P.S. I tried some solutions already from first page google -> stack = no results. If you want to make -1 please make a note and I will improve my skill in working with stackoverflow.

Thank you

Comment: Make sure that the package name of your app is same as the package name mentioned in your _google-services.json_ file.

Comment: It is i checked it already

Comment: Are you _certain_ that your `google-services.json` file has a block [like this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38198021/4815718) with the correct package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to connect to Firebase but you don't have a `dependencies` of Firebase at all. If you want to use `Firebase Realtime Database` and `Firebase Cloud Messaging` as I see in your tags, please add in your `build.gradle` file, the following lines of code:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0
```

If you want other services, see how to [Add Firebase to Your Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Don't forget to redownload the `google-services.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

Download `google-services.json` again. that might be changed somehow.