# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am getting an error while synchronising my gradle file after adding the dependencies for firebase. 
Here is my build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.practicumproject.practicumproject"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'

}
```

Why am I getting this error? Could anyone help me to resolve this?
I am getting error like this:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1.
>   Open File
>   Show Details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom of the file

Follow this setup here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Remove:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

since it is deprecated according to this page:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

Please do this:

- Click **Tools** > **Firebase** to open the Assistant window.
- Click to expand one of the listed features (for example, Analytics), then click the provided tutorial link (for example, Log an Analytics event).
- Click the Connect to Firebase button to connect to Firebase and add the necessary code to your app.

Comment: After adding this I am getting the error `Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
Open File`

Comment: add `google()` repo in the top level build.gradle file, check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Sir, I've checked your answer but after adding the repo synced successfully but while building it is showing an error `No matching client found for package name 'com.practicumproject.practicumproject'`, what does this mean?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf. You are building a new project?

Comment: check the edit in the answer and do **exactly** as it says in the answer