# No matching client found for package name (Google Analytics) - multiple productFlavors/application ids

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am setting up Firebase for my Android application and have run into a slight wrinkle/problem.  I have multiple product flavors such as the standard **dev**, **qa** and **prod**.  These product flavors share the same application id.  However, I have one flavor where the application id is different:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationId "com.acme.myandroidapp"
    }
    qa {
        applicationId "com.acme.myandroidapp"
    }
    foo {
        applicationId "com.acme.foo"
    }
    prod {
        applicationId "com.acme.myandroidapp"
    }
```

This is causing my gradle build to fail with a "No matching client found for package name 'com.acme.foo'" error.

I have looked at both: [No matching client found for package name (Google Analytics) - multiple productFlavors & buildTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf) and [google-services.json for different productFlavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772201/google-services-json-for-different-productflavors)

Unfortunately, neither question deals with the wrinkle of having a different application id for a particular product flavor.  I did try putting a copy of the google-services.json file at the base of each flavor but there was no joy.

Thoughts on how do you support different applicationIds with Google Services under Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Add app for both the application Ids in Project setting in Firebase Console.

By doing so the new google-services.json file will contain two client-info, 1 for each application ID.

Putting a copy of the google-services.json file at  at the base of each flavor should solve the issue.