# No matching client found for package name - productFlavors & buildTypes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have project with multiple product flavor. Have separate projects for each project in firebase console.
Which works fine for ***productFlavor*** with same name as in manifest/gradle file. If I change the productFlavor to other, getting this error.

***No matching client found for package name 'com.my.app.package.name'***

I have added the .json files to each flavor under app/src/{flavor}.

```
app/src/
main/google-services.json
dogfood/google-services.json
mytype1/google-services.json
```

I have gone through the other questions regarding this. But not helpful.

- [No matching client found for package name (Google Analytics) - multiple productFlavors & buildTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf)
- [No matching client found for package name (Google Analytics) - multiple productFlavors/application ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838694/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf) {Suggested to add all projects to one. But I don't want to add all the projects to one.}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you [add an app](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9326094) with that package name/bundle id in the Firebase console?

Comment: @Kato Yes, I have added.