# Rename Android package name

Tags: android, package

hi is there a way I can rename the package name using this format

`live.company.appname.client` instead of just `com.client` alone

I tried it using my desired package name but it keeps getting `com.client`

or com + the last word after the last "."

The reason I am doing this is that I have a that required a package name and the package name I set in that library is fixed and I can't change it

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/9994418)

Comment: since you want to add a new package/folder or ".", u will have to create a new project & copy paste everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**`applicationId`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) exactly matches the Java-style package name you chose
>   during setup. However, the application ID and package name are
>   independent of each other beyond this point. You can change your
>   code's package name (your code namespace) and it will not affect the
>   application ID, and vice versa (though, again, you should not change
>   your application ID once you publish your app).

Your ***application ID*** is defined with the **`applicationId`** property in your **module's** `build.gradle` file.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "live.company.appname.client"
      }
```

Comment: I try it............

Comment: it says `No matching client found for package name`

Comment: @Beginner is there any google json file there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf

Comment: AH I should change google-services.json too?

Comment: @Beginner from your firebase/play console set latest `applicationId` just.

Comment: @Beginner `should change google-services.json too` yes. Create new and set latest `applicationId `.

Comment: it works :D thanks