# How do I install debug ApK over playstore APK

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, testing, adb

I have the Playstore application installed on my mobile! I want to debug that mobile application with my debug APK of the same project. Is there any way to debug that application?
I don't want to uninstall the existing application for data. Right now I am getting a signature error when I try to install debug APK over Playstore APK.

Comment: Do you want to install both PlayStore apk and debug apk on device?

Comment: you cant override play store apk with debug if thats what your intent is.

Comment: I want to debug the data of that application can I install the debug APK alongside with Playstore App and accessing the data of the same application?

Comment: @Sahil yes sahil that is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to install **both** PlayStore apk and your **Debug** Apk on device you can use build types **applicationIdSuffix** as below

Add this to your **app** level **build.gradle**

```
android {

    ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            // Change to true if you want to apply ProGuard minify
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Using this `applicationIdSuffix ".debug"` when you build **debug apk** and install it from android studio it will append `.debug` on your existing package name

for example

- PlayStore package name : **com.example.myapp**
- Debug Package name : **com.example.myapp.debug**

In this way you can **keep both the versions** of your apk on device and debug your apk as you want.

---

**Edit 1**

If you are using Google Services with **google-services.json** you may face following errors

- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. - [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/3624647)
- No matching client found for package name - [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990999/3624647)

This is because of google-services.json need to match the package name and you need to have multiple google-services.json if you want to have multiple app flavors like **Debug** and **Release**

So as per [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

> The google-services.json file is generally placed in the app/ directory (at the root of the Android Studio app module). As of version 2.2.0 the plugin supports build type and product flavor specific JSON files. All of the following directory structures are valid:

```
// dogfood and release are build types.
app/
    google-services.json
    src/dogfood/google-services.json
    src/release/google-services.json
    ...
```

Comment: I am getting this error while compiling 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'org.ird.android.norad.debug'

Comment: It looks like you are using google services with google-services.json right? In that case follow instructions here to manage google-services.json for different flavours https://stackoverflow.com/a/34364376/3624647

Comment: No matching client found for package name we are getting kind of an error

Comment: @RajanBhavsar Its the same. Checkout above link or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990999/3624647. It explains how to manage google-services.json for multiple flavours