# Android build variant not working with different flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-flavors

I have approx 20 different flavors in my application. Previously it was working fine since last 1 year, But after updating to new gradle version 4.4 it starts raising an issue which is **No matching client found for package name**.

Note: Only default flavor is working file now.

Please advise me to fix this issue,

I have fixed that issue now error is

```
Error:cannot access Hide
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileKissgc_customerDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId 'com.mobile.test'
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26

            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 46
            versionName "1"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // minifyEnabled true
                false

    //            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
    //                    'proguard-rules.pro'
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
        productFlavors {
            test{
                minSdkVersion 19
                applicationId 'com.mobile.test'
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 46
                versionName '1.0'
                flavorDimensions "default"
    //            deploy = "release|staging"
            }
            test1{
                minSdkVersion 19
                applicationId 'com.mobile.test1'
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 7777810
                versionName '1.0'
            }
}

  compile ("android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:12.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
   // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:1.0.6'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.0'
```

Thanks
Amit Sharma

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf

Comment: @NileshRathod my code is as per this link.

Comment: I havent changed anything just updated the gradle

Comment: if your package name changed for different flavor, you have to add different *google-services.json*  files.

Comment: Can we see the gradle file ? Maybe is here question about missing `dimension` ? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors

Comment: @Bruno, Please check my updated question

Answer (score 2):

In new gradle version, it is mandatory to define flavorDimensions before defining the productflavors. If you don't have any dimensions to mentioned. Then by default, you have to define flavorDimensions "default"

```
 flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        test {
            applicationId "com.example.test"
        }

        tester {
            applicationId "com.example.tester"
        }
}
```

Comment: Still same issue resists

Comment: Have you used firebase in your project and added googleservices.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions should be defined in above scope, not in each flavor

Each flavor should refer an existing dimension

```
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
            test{
                dimension "default"
                minSdkVersion 19
                applicationId 'com.mobile.test'
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 46
                versionName '1.0'
    //            deploy = "release|staging"
            }
            test1{
                dimension "default"
                minSdkVersion 19
                applicationId 'com.mobile.test1'
                targetSdkVersion 27
                versionCode 7777810
                versionName '1.0'
            }
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue resists