# Google API gradle errors when trying to compile code in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, google-api

I was following a guide on how to make an application similar to uber, I seem to have come across an issue not resolved by the guide. How do I get Android Studio to find the matching client for my package name? Also how do I go about updating the stated firebase build in the code?

I get a error that reads "org.gradle.api.GradleException: No matching client found for package name 'com.NovaTaxi.uber'"

The first solution I was able to find and test was changing the name of my file so that it didnt match the project name and that was of no help. Next I tried to download the completed version of the code to see if it would run for me, in an attempt to find what was wrong and replace it in my own work. To no avail it also wouldn't run because of the same error.

There is a lot of the code and I can't pin-point the error, so I will provide part of the error, and then a link to the vide/github so that you have a better scope of things.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.NovaTaxi.uber"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'

    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

There should be no error but because of what I assume is an issue with the gradle compatibles it wont compile.

Comment: Did you confirm google-services.json has the correct package name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf