# How to have debug, beta and prod builds installed at the same time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i'm trying this [tutorial](https://medium.com/yplan-eng/how-to-have-debug-beta-and-prod-builds-installed-at-the-same-time-696ec4c76211) but in the step 2, i got this error message:

> No matching client found for package name 'com.cinephile.good.beta'

I thinks the Android Studio automaticly make the package so, i just trying using invalidate, and still got same message.

I hope someone can teach me how to handle this error, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf?answertab=votes#tab-top)?

Comment: I put the google-service.json on /app, it's wrong?

Comment: but my google-service.json just for 'com.cinphile.good', should i create for beta then put on app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add **"com.cinephile.good.beta"** as app in Firebase Project as different app in same project and download a json file again and put into beta product flavour it will work.

Comment: Where directory must i put the json file?

Comment: create productFlavors for beta flavour and same name directory equivalent to main directory.