# Flutter app is crashing after 'flutter clean' and debug

Tags: flutter

I don't understand why everything is not working after I did a 'flutter clean'. At nearly the same time I accidentally pressed the Debug button near the play button. Not sure which one messed things up though. Here is the message I get in the console:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.activities'
```

Comment: I think you newly use google-service like firebase, FCM or, etc. You have to add `google-services.json` that you can get from the firebase console into the folder `android/app`.

Comment: Check this. Your package names probably don't match. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and recreated the google-services.json file from Firebase. The Android Package Name that I chose, after clicking to add an Android App, was incorrect. It wasn't the same as the one I used when I made my app.

I also had to add `multiDexEnabled true` in the the default config {} of the app\build.gradle file. So now it looks like:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.activities"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Seems like a non-good idea to add multiDexEnabled to true but it works for now.