# Connecting to firestore error because of changing package name (New Firestore project?)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I changed my package name and application Id of my app because at the beginning I used a testname. The Problem is that i already created a firestore connection with the old package name and now I get an error when I try to start the app:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'my.new.packagename'
```

Is it possible to create a new firestore project with the new package name? Can I just start a new project or do I need to pay attention to a specific thing? For the old firestore connection I asked a freelancer so I dont know exactly how to do this.
Hope you understand my problem and can help me.

Comment: You'll need to update the package name in a few more places than just your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+no+matching+client+found+for+package+name

Comment: I updated the package name with the package: change_app_package_name so it gets updated everywhere. The problem is that i cant edit it in firestore. So i created a new firestore project and conected it with my app. Now my question is if i can simply to that or do i need to pay attention at some point because i already had a firestore project for this app?

Comment: Instead of creating a new project, you can add a new Android app definition to your Firebase project for the new package name.

Comment: I already created a new project. Is this a problem or is this ok? Can I delete the old project?