# How to keep a Java file for two flavors and exclude it for others in my app?

Tags: android, gradle, android-flavors

I have an Android app with, say, three flavors. The first one is called `free`. The second flavor is called `paid`. And the third flavor is called `b2bClient`.

`free` and `pro` need a library (let it be Google Analytics), and, in order to avoid code duplication, the helper class `GoogleAnalyticsHelper` surrounding calls to Google Analytics is in the main source set. But `b2bClient` doesn't use the library. To reduce the size of the `b2bClient` APK, I don't include the library to its dependencies in Gradle. It causes a compilation error when I run `assembleB2bClient` which is obvious (the build system just doesn't have classes from `com.google.android.gms.analytics`.

I tried excluding `GoogleAnalyticsHelper` from the source set when the flavor is `b2bClient` like this:

```
sourceSets {

    main {
        android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
            if (flavor.name == "b2bClient") {
                java.exclude("**/GoogleAnalyticsHelper.java")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

That didn't work, either. The same error. Is it possible to exclude a class from the main source set for a specific flavor?

Comment: Why not create a library which includes the GoogleAnalyticsHelper class and include this library-module in three flavors but not in b2bClient flavor.

Comment: @SagarTrehan if you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Posted answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 0):

Create a library module say `analytics` which contains the code of `GoogleAnalyticsHelper`. Now add this `analytics` library only for flavor requires `analytics` behavior.

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389091/gradle-add-dependency-for-a-specific-flavour-of-the-library) to include a library for a specific flavor only.