# How I can use my one module or library to a specific product flavour

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I have my android Project with five Product flavour as:

```
 productFlavors {
    'Dev' {
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product"]
    }

    'Diamond' {
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product-Diamond"]
        applicationId GROUP.toString() + ".oc"
    }

    'Gold' {
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product-Gold"]
        applicationId GROUP.toString() + ".Gold"
    }

    'Silver' {
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product-Silver"]
        applicationId GROUP.toString() + ".Silver"
    }

    'Bronze' {
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product-bronze"]
        applicationId GROUP.toString() + ".bronze"
    }
 }
```

And I have one module name as `premimum`, which I'm including to my main project using:

```
dependencies {
 implementation project(path: ':premimum')
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, I just want to use this module`premimum`, inside `Dev` and `Diamond` flavour, I want to add the `premimum`dependency only for these two flavour, how can I do that.

My gradle file:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.binarybuff.appgo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        Dev {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product"]
        }

        Diamond {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product-Diamond"]
            applicationId "com.binarybuff.appgo" + ".oc"
        }

        Gold {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product-Gold"]
            applicationId "com.binarybuff.appgo" + ".Gold"
        }

        Silver {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product-Silver"]
            applicationId "com.binarybuff.appgo" + ".Silver"
        }

        Bronze {
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product-bronze"]
            applicationId "com.binarybuff.appgo" + ".bronze"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//    implementation project(path: ':premium')
//    DiamondImplementation project(":premium")
    DiamondImplementation project(path: ':premium' )
}
```

I already look for this and found:
[Library Publication](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication)

[Gradle: add dependency for a specific flavour of the library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26249615/4961126)

I follow the above links but failed. please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
 implementationPremium project(path: ':premimum')
}
```

You can do that by writing **variantName + implementation**. Your project may not be compiled if source directories are suitable up to your partial dependencies.

You can avoid it by writing

```
dependencies {
 provided project(path: ':premimum')
}
```

But make sure dont execute it for variants did not have that dependency otherwise you have [ClassNotFoundException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException)

Comment: thanks, but this didn't help, I got error `Could not find method implementationDevDebug() for arguments [DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ‘:premimum’’, configuration=‘DevDebug’}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

Answer (score 0):

To configure a dependency for a specific build variant, you could prefix the name of the build variant before the Implementation keyword, as below example:

```
dependencies {
    // Adds the local "mylibrary" module as a dependency to the "free" flavor.
    freeImplementation project(":mylibrary")
}
```

please modify your `build.gradle` file like above example.

**Edited:**

```
Dev {  //not 'Dev'
    manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Product"]
}
```

Comment: i tried this but getting the error `cannot resolve the symbol `DevImplementation` `

Comment: I also tried and successful, could you post complete build.gradle file?see my edited answer.

Comment: I added my gradle file

Comment: @HAXM so what's current result? still failed? 
Try:　　DiamondImplementation project(":premium")

Comment: yes, actually I created a demo to see if I'm doing every thing correct, still no luck, the given file is also from the demo project. same error `cannot resolve the symbol DiamondImplementation`

Comment: File | Invalidate Caches then clean or rebuild project

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182086/discussion-between-haxm-and-navylover).

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the configuration as well. As you don't have flavours in your library module, setting configuration as 'default' should work for you. Here are the two lines of code you wanna add

```
DevImplementation project(path: ':premimum', configuration: 'default')
DiamondImplementation project(path: ':premimum', configuration: 'default')
```